# How to capture remote network traffic in wireshark?

Tags: linux, windows, wireshark

Scenario: I have two remote linux machines A and B. I am connecting from Windows where I want to capture "live" n/w traffic of machine B.

The hurdle here is I can access machine B through A only. So, if I need to connect to machine B, I would have to connect to machine A, from there ssh'ing to machine B.

Till now, I have been able to collect n/w packets from machine B to machine A using the following command

> tcpdump -s0 -U -n -w - -i lo not port 22 | ssh user@ip_of_A  "cat >  ~/some_file.pcap"

Now, how can I view the live traffic from machine A to windows. Right now, I am copying pcap to windows manually and viewing in wireshark. Can this be automated in some sense or is there a better way to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _If_ you connect to A with PuTTY's plink, and your profile/bashrc/etc files are well-behaved, you could do `plink >local.pcap u@A ssh u@B tcpdump -w- ...` to get the data back to a local (Windows) file in one step, then open it in Wireshark. It's still not 'live', you have to end the capture before opening it. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Could you please move the question to the appropriate place if you think so?